# How to combine or connect ArcGIS to eCogntion (Trimble)?

Tags: arcgis

I'm using eCognition for object-based image analysis, and ArcGIS for spatial analysis, and I want to combine them into a single application

Answer (score 0):

You can consider building a plugin for ArcGIS in Python or javascript and then accessing the API of eCognition Server. ArcGIS also has an API but that might be hard to integrate.